# Building apk file manually in Titanium appcelerator

Tags: titanium

I am working on Titanium appcelerator. I have successfully develope one application. In my application's Resource folder I created one folder named "XmlFiles" in which 2 xml files are there. Application use these xml files. Now what I am trying to do is when I will change these two xml files(using Titanium desktop application) apk file should be build(generated with respect to our new xml files). So my question is how to manually build apk file from Titanium, or is there any other alternate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Titanium CLI is should be installed for this purpose only.
You can carry out every operation of titanium through the command line.

May be [this link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Command-Line_Interface_Reference-section-35619828_TitaniumCommand-LineInterfaceReference-Build) can provide more information.